# Creating a stored procedure with ARRAY input argument in AS400

Tags: arrays, stored-procedures, db2

I'm currently working on an AS400 machine to create a stored procedure which accepts a string array as an input argument. My code is as follow:

```
CREATE TYPE stringArray as VARCHAR(100) array[100] 
CREATE PROCEDURE ALI/LWRH_SP
(
    IN list stringArray
)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    --TO DO SOME WORK
END
```

Unfortunately, when I run the mentioned code, the system gives me an error:

> SQL0104: token array was not valid. valid tokens:END-OF-STATEMENT

Does anyone know how I can manage this error?

Comment: Edit your question to add the *version* of the Db2 for i that you are using.  If your version is IBM i 6.1 then you may be out of luck, as the docs suggest that only IBM i 7.1 or higher supports array types on SQL procedures. Also try qualifying the type name where used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version is IBM i 6.1 (or lower) then you may be out of luck, as the docs suggest that only IBM i 7.1 or higher supports array types on SQL procedures.